# heroku login gives undefined method 'remove' for QuickLoader module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am a newbiw trying to walk through rails tutorials by Michael Hartl. I upgraded Ruby and Rails recently. I am able to launch a dummy application and push it to git. However, when I try to login to heroku, it fails with below error

```
$ heroku login
/Users/krishnabhat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rubygems-update-2.3.0/lib/rubygems/compatibility.rb:19:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `remove' for Gem::QuickLoader:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/krishnabhat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rubygems-update-2.3.0/lib/rubygems.rb:15:in `require'
    from /Users/krishnabhat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rubygems-update-2.3.0/lib/rubygems.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:158:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:158:in `load_full_rubygems_library'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:212:in `push_gem_version_on_load_path'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:16:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/heroku:18:in `<main>'

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.6.2

$ gem -v
2.3.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]
```

Please assist.

Thanks
K

Comment: Can you expand on "trying to login to heroku" ? What do you literally type and where (obviously password etc keep secret)?

Comment: I just type the below command and get the above errors. I have already executed the steps needed to deploy heroku

$ heroku login

Comment: Same error occurs for "heroku create"

Comment: what happens when you "bundle install"

Comment: bundle install and bundle update runs successfully as seen below

Comment: $ bundle install
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.12.1
Using sprockets-rails 2.0.1
Using rails 4.0.8
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using rspec-core 2.13.1
Using rspec-expectations 2.13.0
Using rspec-mocks 2.13.1
Using rspec-rails 2.13.1
Using rubyzip 0.9.9
Using sass 3.3.9
Using sass-rails 4.0.1
Using sdoc 0.3.20
Using websocket 1.0.7
Using selenium-webdriver 2.35.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.8
Using turbolinks 1.1.1
Using uglifier 2.1.1
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Comment: I get the same error for autotest too

Comment: might be worth talking to heroku support?